# Blender showing this warning and I can't seem to get rid of it

Tags: keymap

Not sure how to get rid of this message. I've tried looking for every single "menu" in the keybinds and couldn't find anything that could solve it

[image]

Comment: are you building your own Blender? Not sure this is the best place to ask about it. Maybe devtalk.blender.org

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)